# "udevadm info" command is not showing ID_BUS data

Tags: linux, udev, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded board having ARM cortex-a53. To add support of "udevadm" on this board, I have downloaded "buildroot-2022.02" (https://buildroot.org/downloads/buildroot-2022.02.tar.gz) and cross-compile for my platform.

When I run **udevadm** command on board I am getting the following output.

```
root@root:~$ udevadm info /dev/sda
P: /devices/platform/2f0b80000.sata/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
N: sda
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/2f0b80000.sata/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=gpt
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=c3723b53-1411-48bc-8eb4-7481fb489854
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6485105
```

I didn't get the value of the "**ID_BUS**" parameter.

When I run "**udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda**" command I am getting the following o/p

```
root@root:~$ udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda
calling: test
version 3.2.11
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

/etc/udev/hwdb.bin does not exist, please run udevadm hwdb --update
Load module index
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
timestamp of '/run/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
specified group 'tty' unknown
specified group 'dialout' unknown
specified group 'kmem' unknown
specified group 'input' unknown
specified group 'video' unknown
specified group 'audio' unknown
specified group 'lp' unknown
specified group 'disk' unknown
specified group 'cdrom' unknown
specified group 'tape' unknown
specified group 'kvm' unknown
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-sensor.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-joystick.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/udev.rules
rules contain 24576 bytes tokens (2048 * 12 bytes), 8335 bytes strings
1096 strings (14316 bytes), 690 de-duplicated (6388 bytes), 407 trie nodes used
GROUP 0 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:59
IMPORT 'ata_id --export /dev/sda' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:38
starting 'ata_id --export /dev/sda'
'ata_id --export /dev/sda'(err) '/lib/udev/ata_id: error while loading shared libraries: libblkid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
'ata_id --export /dev/sda' [1728] exit with return code 127
IMPORT 'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sda' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:50
starting 'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sda'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sda'(err) '/lib/udev/scsi_id: error while loading shared libraries: libblkid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or direc
tory'
'scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d /dev/sda' [1729] exit with return code 127
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:73
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'blkid' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:90
probe /dev/sda raid offset=0
handling device node '/dev/sda', devnum=b8:0, mode=0600, uid=0, gid=0
preserve permissions /dev/sda, 060600, uid=0, gid=0
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/block/8:0' to '../sda'
created db file '/run/udev/data/b8:0' for '/devices/platform/2f0b90000.sata/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda'
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/2f0b90000.sata/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=gpt
ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=c54841fb-8cb1-424c-a579-900948226b73
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SUBSYSTEM=block
USEC_INITIALIZED=6649798
Unload module index
root@root:~$
```

The summary of the above o/p is, The following rule, written in "**/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules**" file is trying to execute "**ata_id --export /dev/sda**" command and getting an error.

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
```

The error I am getting is

```
starting 'ata_id --export /dev/sda'
'ata_id --export /dev/sda'(err) '/lib/udev/ata_id: error while loading shared libraries: libblkid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
'ata_id --export /dev/sda' [1728] exit with return code 127
```

But when I run "**ata_id --export /dev/sda**" command from the terminal I am getting the following o/p. It didn't show an error

```
root@root:~$ ata_id --export /dev/sda
ID_ATA=1
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_BUS=ata
ID_MODEL=ST1000NM0011
ID_MODEL_ENC=ST1000NM0011\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x2 0\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_REVISION=PA07
ID_SERIAL=ST1000NM0011_Z1N2YF10
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=Z1N2YF10
ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE=1
ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE_ENABLED=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_HPA=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_HPA_ENABLED=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM_ENABLED=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ENABLED=0
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ERASE_UNIT_MIN=150
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ENHANCED_ERASE_UNIT_MIN=150
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART_ENABLED=1
ID_ATA_DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE=1
ID_ATA_SATA=1
ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN2=1
ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN1=1
ID_ATA_ROTATION_RATE_RPM=7200
ID_WWN=0x5000c5004ecabf57
ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5000c5004ecabf57
root@root:~$
```

When I run ldd command on ata_id, it didn't know any linking problem.

```
root@root:~$ ldd /lib/udev/ata_id
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007fbd357000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/libblkid.so.1 (0x0000007fbd2a5000)
libkmod.so.2 => /lib/libkmod.so.2 (0x0000007fbd281000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0000007fbd117000)
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007fbd329000)
root@root:~$ ls -l /lib/libblkid.so.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Sep 30 05:19 /lib/libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 316112 Nov 29 12:01 /lib/libblkid.so.1.1.0
root@root:~$
```

**So my question is, Why does udev rule throw an error?**

Comment: Maybe because the initramfs doesn't have the library?

Comment: Once the device is booted, I am running "udevadm test /sys/class/block/sda" command. and libblkid.so.1 lib present at /lib in rootfs.